# Problems encountered with the Q-Vector Example of MetPy

Tags: metpy

I'm trying to reproduce the [Q-Vector example in MetPy](https://unidata.github.io/python-gallery/examples/850hPa_QVectors.html), and am getting an error when applying the command:

```
q_div = -2*mpcalc.divergence(uqvect, vqvect, dx, dy, dim_order='yx')
```

> Error: 
>   ValueError: `divergence` given arguments with incorrect units: `u` requires "[speed]" but given "meter ** 2 / kilogram / second", `v` requires "[speed]" but given "meter ** 2 / kilogram / second".

I don't know how to circumvent this problem, because `uqvect` and `vqvect` must have the units `meter**2/kilogram/second`. Any ideas? Or is there a general problem with the MetPy Code, because I just took the code from the MetPy Homepage.

Comment: Would you be able to share what version of MetPy you are using when running into this issue? The appears to be due to a bug that was fixed in version 0.11.1 (see https://github.com/Unidata/MetPy/pull/1197).

Comment: I used version 0.11.0, after updating to 0.12.0 everything works! Thank you for the comment.